# Orange HRM is not getting Logged

Tags: orangehrm

I have installed OrangeHRM 3.1.2 in live server and accessing through a domain name.

Issue I am facing is - When I am trying to loggin to the following link "http://example.com/hrm/symfony/web/index.php/auth/login" - With valid credentials. I was not logged in or neither I am not displayed with any exceptional Message, but I was able to see the URL as follows - "http://example.com/hrm/symfony/web/index.php/pim/viewMyDetails" which means I have logged in but the screen have not changed and I am still seeing the Login screen.

The Orange HRM is hosted in Godaddy Linux hosting.
I am using Windows 7.
I have checked this scenario in cross browser as well.

When I tried after few or many mins,  I was able to login without any issues. As I am facing this issues frequently. I am unable to track My Staffs login and logout time exactly.

As I am not a developer, I am not sure what was the issue. Can someone please help me solving the same and just let me know if you need any more information.

Appreciate your valuable response.

Thanks,
Karthi

Answer (score 1):

Please check your php session save path. Make sure it is writable by the webserver you are running , either apache or nginx or php-fpm. I had the same issue and i was able to solve giving proper permissions to the session save path directory.